# How to achieve vertical align of div

Tags: css

I have one div with id="content". It is inside body and contain all data on side.

```
<body>
<div id="content">
</div>
</body>
```

How to achieve vertical align of this div ? I tried with vertical-align:middle; in style but it doesn't work. Can anybody help ?

Answer (score 1):

you may get idea form here:

```
<div id="t01" class="tag">
  <div class="small">
    <div class="globe-arrow"></div>
  </div>
</div>

.tag {background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;
    display: block;
    height: 400px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -200px;
    margin-top: -200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 400px}
.small { background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EBEBEB;
    height: 300px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
    margin-top: -150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 300px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

its easy you can use this:

```
#content {
margin: 0 auto;
width:960px;
position:relative
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Solution Matched me perfectly. Even if it is a link or just a text inside the div, this CSS Class could vertically align the content inside the DIV

```
 .verticalCenterDivText{
        height: 29px;
        line-height: 29px;
    }
```